# Creating a custom made simple machine to dislodge extremely tight gas lifts from the mechanism

Tags: machine-design

I am asking here because I'm considering designing a simple custom made machine unless I find a machine or a specialized tool that can help me pop off the gas lift from the mechanism.

Most demonstrations I find online don't have the gas lift as tight as the one I have. The person claims he is at 120 kg (264.55 lbs) of weight but it's possible they are even heavier. There was never an issue with this chair model with other people using it, but maybe the weight of the user is on the heavy side (although the maximum weight capacity of the chair was supposedly at 150 kg)

I have tried using WD-40 on several applications while attempting to loosen it hoping that even the slightest bit more of WD-40 can help dislodge it. Here are some photos:

What I have tried doing:

1. Hammering the mechanism with a rubber mallet. Also, trying to hammer the gas lift side-to-side to try get WD-40 in the gaps.
2. Using a pipe wrench (although the gas lift may get deep scratches due to how tight it is or might even dent the gas lift). I am getting some level of scratching on the gas lift and I'm worried if I really strain and put all my strength it might break. If the gas lift breaks I'd be stuck with having to also try to remove the gas lift from the star base which is a nightmare.

[image]

3. Adding 2 - 3 dumbbells (80 lbs total weight is all I could find but nothing close to 264.55 lbs of weight. I am thinking if I should make some contraption that can increase the weight placed on top of the mechanism while inverted and let gravity do its work). I had the weights on for about two days and even if I push down with a lot of force it's still not moving.

[image]

What I've considered using:

1. Bearing separator - My issue with these is that the rods need to be at least 7 inches apart since it is the width of the mechanism I want to remove and I read it's usually less than this.

[image]

2. Jaw Puller - I read that the object should be circular and since the mechanism is not a thick metal object, it may warp on the jaws under high loads.

[image]

3. Gas Lift Removal Tool - I cannot find the product locally and I'm importing one, but it's going to take too long before I get my hands on it. Also, not sure if it can also output enough force

[image]

[image]

4. Heating the metal - Since the gas lift is pressured I don't know if it can blow up in any case.
5. Liquid nitrogen - Also read it's not advisable due to safety issues and may not be effective since the shrinking effect is negligible

Comment: that is a gas spring

Comment: this looks like an XY question ... asking for help with a perceived solution to a problem, instead of asking for help with the problem itself

Comment: what exactly is the problem? ... how is the 120 kg person related to the problem?

Comment: maybe you are trying to unscrew something that is welded together

Comment: The gas lift is connected to the 5-star base (where the wheels are located) and to the mechanism (the one with levers controlling the gas lift elevation and the backrest recline of the chair itself). If the person is heavier the gas lift locks deeper into the 5-star base and the mechanism. So my problem is that the gas lift is so tight that I can't remove it from the mechanism even with a lot of force and need better methods to pop it out. It is not welded because I am the one assembling the chairs, and you simply shoot it in without any adhesive. There are no locks to it as well

Comment: So all solutions that I found online to try tackle my main problem isn't working (pipe wrench, WD-40, hammering the mechanism) and other suggested solutions seem dangerous or not ideal (heating the mechanism, jaw puller, bearing separator, gas lift removal tool). I believe creating a custom made puller can clamp on the mechanism and pull the gas lift off and i'm trying to find ways I can engineer this

Comment: I've read your post several times and I do not understand what the problem actually is ... it is unclear what is stuck to what ... is it the picture with the hammer that illustrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: The first photo with the pipe wrench is the 2 pieces I need separated. (1) Gas lift (where the pipe wrench is clamped on) and (2) mechanism (black metal rectangular-looking plate)

Comment: then show a closeups of the problem area, from both sides of the seat base (black rectangle), and also a closeup of each of the mating parts ... your post contains a lot of irrelevant information that muddies the actual problem